# I have found an analogue device that has an active input but can't find a way to disable it. How do I do that?

Tags: windows, hardware-detection, input-device

This is the second time I try to find a "ghost device" that gives "random" inputs since there aren't any built in tools to make it easy. I have managed to find out that it's an analogue device that should have the VID:BEEF and PID:046D but that device don't seem to exist. Just to rule out the option that the ID numbers are reversed I have disabled all devices with VID:046D but still got the same input.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't think of it earlier but in dxdiag you can see a list of input devices and there I could find the VID and PID for the input devices and find the device that didn't list them in the device property.

Using the information from dxdiag you should be able to find the device in the device manager and disable it.

[image]

Comment: Is this intended as additional info to your question, or as a solution? If the former. you should delete this and edit [your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1776986/edit) instead to add new info. If the latter, you should edit [the answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1776990/edit) to clarify how exactly this resolves the question of disabling a device.